# Cannot modify the document for either a read-only external command is being executed, or changes to the document are temporarily disabled

Tags: c#, revit-api

I want to set parameter values of the elements when the `DocumentChanged` event is triggered. I know that the event is read-only.

Is there any another way (except `IUpdater`) to do it? Except `IUpdater` because I want every changes in the document.

Here is my code

```
public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
{
  try
  {
     // Event handler for document changing
     application.ControlledApplication.DocumentChanged += new EventHandler<DocumentChangedEventArgs>(Application_DocumentChanged);
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
     return Result.Failed;
  }
  return Result.Succeeded;
}

private void Application_DocumentChanged(object sender, DocumentChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Document doc = e.GetDocument();
   // Record added elements
   if (e.GetAddedElementIds().Count() > 0)
   {
      using (Transaction transaction = new Transaction(doc))
      {
         try
         {
            transaction.Start("Set TCP Parameters");
            foreach(ElementId el_id in e.GetAddedElementIds())
            {
                 doc.GetElement(element_id).get_Parameter(new Guid("6558f207-e777-0758-2023-2f34e722cb01")).Set(200)
            }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            TaskDialog.Show("Error: Transaction", ex.Message);
         }
         transaction.Commit();
       }
    }
  TaskDialog.Show("Document Changed", e.Operation.ToString());
}
```

I will really appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 1):

You ask: Is there any another way?

Yes. You can subscribe to a one-off shot of the `Idling` event, cf. [Reacting to Changes and Setting Parameters using DMU or DocumentChanged](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/07/clicks-dmu-surfaces-firerating-feedback-vacation.html#3)

This has been discussed repeatedly by [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/) and in the [Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160). Some related articles are listed in the topic group on [Idling and External Events for Modeless Access and Driving Revit from Outside](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28).

Comment: Yes, I have been asking for any other ways, that can be modified parameters of newly added elements. Thank you very much @JeremyTammik for recommendations, but now I don't have access to the server of [The Building Coder]. Can you give any example for idling events,

Comment: You can access all The Building Coder blog posts in source text format from the [tbc GetHub repo](https://github.com/jeremytammik/tbc): [offline index](https://jeremytammik.github.io/tbc/a/); [offline topic group 5.28](https://jeremytammik.github.io/tbc/a/#5.28);